# Active Directory Access logging

Tags: active-directory, logging

We are running Active Directory on windows server 2012 and are looking to create a report of users daily usage by logging the login time and log out time of each user.

The aim is to database these logs for access in an intranet.

We have tried adding a bat file to each DC Users Profile > Logon Script to trigger the logging however this seems a little inefficient as we would need to apply this to each user of the AD and will only work for logging logons.

Are there any better ways to achieve this?

Comment: Have you looked into using Group Policy to apply a logon/logoff script for all users? My 2012 skills need a little brushing up otherwise if this doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: Can't this be collected from the event logs?  As the domain admin, you CAN get to all the event logs on all systems.